# Dealing with arrays in HDL

Tags: verilog, hdl

*(Assume `Mux4Way` has been already implemented)*

```
/**
 * 4-way 16-bit multiplexor:
 * out = a if sel == 00
 *       b if sel == 01
 *       c if sel == 10
 *       d if sel == 11
 */

CHIP Mux4Way16 {
    IN a[16], b[16], c[16], d[16], sel[2];
    OUT out[16];

    PARTS:
    // Put your code here:
    Mux4Way(a=a[0],b=b[0],c=c[0],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[0]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[1],b=b[1],c=c[1],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[1]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[2],b=b[2],c=c[2],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[2]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[3],b=b[3],c=c[3],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[3]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[4],b=b[4],c=c[4],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[4]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[5],b=b[5],c=c[5],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[5]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[6],b=b[6],c=c[6],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[6]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[7],b=b[7],c=c[7],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[7]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[8],b=b[8],c=c[8],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[8]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[9],b=b[9],c=c[9],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[9]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[10],b=b[10],c=c[10],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[10]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[11],b=b[11],c=c[11],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[11]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[12],b=b[12],c=c[12],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[12]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[13],b=b[13],c=c[13],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[13]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[14],b=b[14],c=c[14],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[14]);
    Mux4Way(a=a[15],b=b[15],c=c[15],d=d[0],sel=sel,out=out[15]);
}
```

As you can see, this code looks quite inelegant. How can I deal with this repetitive code? I'm new to HDL, so I apologize for this trivial question. Is there the concept of loops (or something like it) in HDL?

Comment: Most languages have a construct that allows you to instantiate arrays of entities. For instance, VHDL has a "generate" statement. I don't recognize your HDL, what language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In verilog you use a generate like:

```
   genvar i;

   generate

     for (i = 0; i < 16 ; i = i + 1) begin: muxes
          Mux4Way m(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.c(c[i]),.d(d[i]),.sel(sel),.out(out[i]));
     end

  endgenerate
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement a mux is to use the array-subscript operator (we don't need to construct a larger mux using smaller ones, the HDL synthesizer does this for us). The SystemVerilog code would look like this:

```
logic  [1:0] select;     // Two bit array index
logic [15:0] in[3:0];    // Four 16-bit numbers
logic [15:0] out;        // 16-bit output

always_comb out = in[sel];

/* If the array "in" is not available, you can create it as:

   always_comb in[0] = a;
   always_comb in[1] = b;
   ...
   always_comb in[3] = d;
*/
```